# java method to store a character at specified location and method to return character at a location?

Tags: java, tostring, multidimensional-array

Ok, so I really need help with the following methods, I really don't know how to start.

The class will need a setRowColumn method. This will take three arguments: two integers to 
specify the row and column, and one character. The method will store the character at the 
speciﬁed location on the board.
The class will need a getRowColumn method. This will take two integer arguments: the row and 
the column. The method will return the character at that location.
The class will need a toString method. This method will create a string that contains the 
contents of the board. Each row of the board will be one line in the string. Draw a border around the board using -’s across the top and bottom, and |’s on each side. Put a + in each corner. 
The following is what I have completed, if you could help me with the two classes and please check my toString method as well. Thank you.

```
public class Board {

    private char [][] theBoard;

    public Board() { // This will not take any arguments
        this(10, 25); // calls the other constructor
    }

    // takes number of rows and columns
    public Board (int rows, int cols) {
        // fix illegal row and column numbers
        if (rows < 1 || rows>80) {
            rows = 1;
        }
        if (cols<1 || cols > 80) {
            cols = 1;
        }
        // create the board and fill it with ' '
        theBoard = new char [rows][cols];
        for (int row = 0; row < theBoard.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < theBoard[row].length; col++)
                theBoard[row][col] = ' ';
        }
    }

    // only puts ' ' into fields not containing any of '0' - '9'
    public void clearBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < theBoard.length; row++ ) {
            for (int col = 0; col < theBoard[row].length; col++) {
                if (theBoard[row][col] < '0' || theBoard[row][col] > '9') {
                    theBoard[row][col] = ' ';   
                }
            }
        }
    }
     public void setRowColumn(int row, int col, char character) {
        int index = 0;

      for ( int i = 1; i <= row; i++ )
         if ( col[i] > col[index] )
            index = i;
      return index;


        }

     public String toString() { //begin toString method
        int i;
        String temp = new String (""); //create string  

            //    drawLine
            String line = "";
            char topBottom = '-';
            int k;
            int row2 = theBoard[0].length;

            for ( k = 0 ; k < row2 ; k++ ){
                    line += topBottom; // adding hyphens
            }
                System.out.println('+' + line + '+'); // adding left and right + corners                

            for (i=0; i<theBoard.length; i++) {
                temp += "|"; //add characters to the string

                for (int j=0; j<theBoard[0].length; j++) {
                    temp = temp + theBoard[i][j] + "|"; //add the actual number to the string
                }
            temp += "\n";
            }

            return line + "\n" + temp + "\n" + line; //return string
        }// end of method toString

}
```

Comment: if you use the code I provided, you might as well accept my answer of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734233/java-constructors-and-clearboard-method-which-clears-board-except-the-positions/13734362#13734362).

Comment: also you kind of put an error in the constructor. If one tries to get 100 rows or columns, they'll get 1 instead of 80. My code in the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734233/java-constructors-and-clearboard-method-which-clears-board-except-the-positions/13734362#13734362) didn't make that mistake.

Comment: This kinda isn't a question. It's basically "Do my homework for me" which ... isn't the purpose of SO.

Comment: Oh I am sorry I am new on this page and didn't know I had to choose an answer but I will do that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to over-complicate things here. Since your board is a 2-dimensional array, we have direct access to all of the positions.

So, setting a character to a specific row/col is done like the following:

```
public void setRowColumn(int row, int col, char character) {
    theBoard[row][col] = character;
}
```

And getting a specific character is done in reverse:

```
public char getRowColumn(int row, int col) {
    return theBoard[row][col];
}
```

Knowing this, you should be able to complete the rest of the pretty-printing of the board.

Comment: yes, I am sorry I always tend to that, but thanks for your help. I really need help with my toString method if you could just tell me if it is wrong or right I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setRowColumn(int row, int col, char character) {
    try {
        theBoard[row][col] = character;
    } catch (ArrayOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // what should happen when one provides illegal indexes?
    }
}
```

and

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char[] chars : theBoard) {
        strb.append(Arrays.toString(chars) + "\n");
    }
    return strb.toString();
}
```

This `toString()` may not produce exactly what you want, imho it's good enough.